# Is it suspicious to think that methods go missing in ruby?

Tags: ruby, class, methods, instance

```
class Person
  def name
    puts "Doharey"
  end
end

puts Person.class #=> this out puts Class
puts Class.methods.count #=> 82 methods
puts Person.methods.count #=> 82 methods
```

In the above example a `Person` class is created which inherits from `Class` and both `Person` and `Class` has equal number of methods.

Now lets instantiate `Person` class

```
a = Person.new
puts a.methods.count #=> 42 methods
```

If `a` is an instance of `Person` then why are the number of methods less in `a` than `Person`. What happens ? how some methods go missing ? Are they not inherited in the first place ? If so how ?

Comment: Your `Person` class does not inherit from `Class`, but from `Object`.

Comment: "Is it suspicious to think that methods go missing in ruby?"  Have you checked in `Kernel#method_missing`?  [Sorry, just couldn't resist.]

Comment: What is `Kernel#methods_missing` ? "[Sorry, just couldn't resist]" => didn't get you, what ?

Comment: Just a bad joke, really. But if you want to learn about `method_missing` (and you should!), take a look here for instance: http://rubylearning.com/blog/2010/10/07/do-you-know-rubys-chainsaw-method/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 a.methods
```

are the instance methods and

```
 Person.methods
```

are class methods. They do not share the same namespace. When you define `name` on `Person` you are defining an instance methods.

```
class Person
  def self.name
    puts "Doharey"
  end
end
=> nil
Person.methods.count
=> 113
Class.methods.count
=> 114
```

Here I've defined a class method which also shows up in the method list.

Comment: That is what i thought first, By definition an object cannot have class methods. and class methods can only be called from uninstantiated class, And not an instance of a class. but 'Person' class itself is an instance of 'Class' class and in effect 'Person' is an object. which is contradictory.

Comment: Also related, `Person.instance_methods` return the list of instance methods, so `Person.instance_methods.count` == `Person.new.methods.count`

Comment: If that is the case how come some of the methods present in :

    `Person.instance_methods` are also present in `Person.methods`

when you said `Person.methods` gives a list of class methods and `Person.instance_methods` gives a list of instance methods. 

And class methods should not be present in an instance. then how come methods like  `inspect`, `object_id` etc.... are present in both lists ?

Comment: Because a class is also an object - an instance of the `Class` class. So what you are seeing is the instance methods of `Class`. If you want to see only the class methods of your own class, use `Person.methods(false)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Person
  def name
    puts "Doharey"
  end
end
```

How many instance methods are there in our new class?

```
Person.instance_methods.size
# => 72
```

List all instance methods of a class, excluding any methods inherited from the superclass:

```
Person.instance_methods(false)
# => [:name]
```

Every new class is by default a subclass of Object:

```
Person.superclass
# => Object
```

How many instance methods are there in the superclass?

```
Object.instance_methods.size
# => 71
```